# How to make toast when user tries to insert text longer than maximum limit?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, toast, textwatcher

How to make a `Toast` to pop up when the user tries to insert text longer than maximum limit?

```
<EditText
    android:maxLength="28"
    ...
 />
```

I tried to use `TextWatcher` but it doesn't work properly:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements TextWatcher
{

    // ...

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0){}

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3){}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
    {
        if(etUsername.isFocused() && etUsername.getText().length() == 28)
            Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "The username must be at most 28 characters!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else if(etPassword.isFocused() && etPassword.getText().length() == 10)
            Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "The password must be at most 10 characters!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I also tried to put the code inside `afterTextChanged` and `beforeTextChanged` but it doesn't solve the problem.

**EDIT2:**

What I want is that the `Toast` only can be popped up when there are 28 characters in the `EditText` and the user is trying to add a 29th character. The `Toast` in my code above will pop up only if there are 27 characters in the `TextEdit` and the user inserts a 28th character.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work properly"?

Comment: @Ogre_BGR I mean it does not work as I want it (The `Toast` only can be popped up when there are 28 characters in the `EditText` and the user is trying to add a 29th character). The `Toast` in my code above will pop up only if there are 27 characters in the `TextEdit` and the user inserts a 28th character.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: then why don't you use 29 instead of 28 in your if condition and after all,discard the last letter of your EditText if it is displays 29 characters even after Toast?

Comment: @Hiral This won't work, because the `EditText` is limited to 28 characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to achieve desired functionality is to change `android:maxLength` to `desiredMaxLength + 1` and to check for the length in `afterTextChanged()`. You will have to manually delete the last character when length == desiredMaxLength + 1 (i.e. manipulate the `s` parameter in `afterTextChanged(Editable s)`). Please be careful not to put yourself in infinite loop because after changing `s` `afterTextChanged()` will be called again.

Comment: +1 This works very well, but still I need to set the caret at the end of the `EditText`

Comment: `etUsername.setSelection(arg0.length() - 1);` solves this issue. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

This solution work for my case:

```
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if(etUsername.isFocused() && etUsername.getText().toString().trim().length() > MAX_CHARS){
        etUsername.setText(s.toString().substring(0, MAX_CHARS));
        etUsername.setSelection(s.length()-1);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Maximum number of characters reached.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
if(etUsername.isFocused() && etUsername.getText().length() == 28)
```

Use this:

```
 if(arg0.length() > 28)
      {
String temp=arg0.subString(0,27)
etUsername.setText(temp);
 //Toast come's here
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Complete code is below. it is working perfectly.

```
String tempReview;
EditText et_userReview;
TextView tv_charactersRemaining;

Public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){

if(s.toString().length() <= 200) {
                 tv_charactersRemaining.setText(200 -   s.toString().length()+ " characters remaining");
                 tempReview = s.toString();
                 } else {
                 et_userReview.setText(tempReview);
                 Editable etext = et_userReview.getText();
                 Selection.setSelection(etext, 200);    
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  "No more characters You have reached the limit.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
```

}